# Xamarin - After image loads, content below the image disappears until device is rotated

Tags: android, xamarin

Really at a loss here.

I'm loading an image into an announcement page:

```cs
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_announcementDetails.ImageUrl))
            {
                this.DefaultLogo.IsVisible = false;
                this.AnnouncementImage.Source = _announcementDetails.ImageUrl;
                this.ImageLogo.IsVisible = true;
            }
```

```xml
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" IsVisible="False"  VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="0" Padding="0,0,0,10" x:Name="ImageLogo">
                    <Image x:Name="AnnouncementImage" 
                           VerticalOptions="Fill"
                           HorizontalOptions="Fill" ></Image>
                </StackLayout>


                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Padding="20,30,20,30" x:Name="MainContent">

                    <Label Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="Empty placeholder bug" x:Name="AnnouncementTitle" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" />
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Empty placeholder body bug" x:Name="AnnouncementBody" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" BorderRadius="2" Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.AboutLearnMore}" VerticalOptions="End" TextColor="White" x:Name="OpenWebsite"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" BorderRadius="2" Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.OK}" VerticalOptions="End" TextColor="White" x:Name="Close"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
```

After the image pops in, when the device is in landscape, any text below disappears. If you rotate the device to portrait and back, the text re-appears.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnjUq.png

Rotate the device to portrait and back...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x66zY.png

Any help? No issues in portrait mode. Running on android.

Comment: Could you share a sample which could reproduce the issue ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT You can build https://github.com/rayshift/translatefgo/ from master and it will display this issue after the initial setup screen.

Comment: Try to add `ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation` to your  `Activity` attribute in your `MainActivity`.

Comment: Already have that there.

Comment: It was weird. I didn't have that problem again.I just set the ConfigurationChanges  above.